# PDF Images not displaying in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, pdf

I have uploaded a PDF onto my website (link below). The PDF shows fine in Chrome and Explorer, but the images are displaying blurred in Firefox. It's not just this document but every PDF file on the website.

http://www.pci-instruments.com/files/datasheet/50.pdf

Comment: Is this using Firefox's built in PDF reader, or something else (e.g. Adobe Reader)? If it's the built-in one, you can report bugs at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with the Firefox built in viewer. You will need to go to **Options**->**Applications** and change the **PDF File** or **Portable Document Format** settings to **Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)**