# Import long html into split PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

My scenario is:

On clicking a button, import datas on a html into a PDF file.

Since this PDF must have some complicated required style, so my first step is to transfer this page into a image using html2canvas.js and then import this image to a PDF with jsPDF.js

And when the data is too large the PDF must be split to hold all the data,to do this,so I used the codes here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/397

My problem is: on firefox the splited page on PDF on page 2 or 3...cannot be shown, they are totally blank. but on page 1 it is fine. (this is for firefox)

I tested other browsers they are all fine. pls someone could throw some light on how to fix this?

Here is my plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ElvAsriK2nssq2U9pgKX?p=preview

```
function initTemplate(){
      datas=getData();
      var templateData=_.template($('#tpl').html(), datas);
      $('#tplW').html(templateData);
      getPDF();
      //  $('#tplW').append(_.template($('#tpl').html(), datas));
      // $('body').html( _.template($('#tpl').html(), datas));

 }


   function getData(){
      var htmlData=$(".MsoNormalTable .inner").find("tr.tablerow");
         var datas=[];
         $.each(htmlData,function(i,v){
             var d=[];
             var tds=$(v).find("td");
             $.each(tds,function(index,val){
                 d.push($(val).text());
             });
              datas.push(d); 
         });
       return datas;
   }



function getPDF() {
    // initTemplate();
         html2canvas($('#tplW')[0], {
        onrendered: function(canvas){

            canvasToImageSuccess(canvas);
        }
    });



    function canvasToImage (canvas){
        var img = new Image();
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        img.src = dataURL;
        return img;
    };


    function canvasShiftImage (oldCanvas,shiftAmt){
        shiftAmt = parseInt(shiftAmt) || 0;
        if(!shiftAmt){ return oldCanvas; }
        var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height - shiftAmt;
        newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
        var ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = canvasToImage(oldCanvas);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0, shiftAmt, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        return newCanvas;
    };



    function canvasToImageSuccess (canvas){
       var pdf = new jsPDF('l','px'),
            pdfInternals = pdf.internal,
            pdfPageSize = pdfInternals.pageSize,
            pdfScaleFactor = pdfInternals.scaleFactor,
            pdfPageWidth = pdfPageSize.width,
            pdfPageHeight = pdfPageSize.height,
            totalPdfHeight = 0,
            htmlPageHeight = canvas.height,
            htmlScaleFactor = canvas.width / (pdfPageWidth * pdfScaleFactor),
            safetyNet = 0;
        while(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight && safetyNet < 15){
            var newCanvas = canvasShiftImage(canvas, totalPdfHeight);
            pdf.addImage(newCanvas, 'png', 0, 0, pdfPageWidth, 0, null, 'NONE');
            totalPdfHeight += (pdfPageHeight * pdfScaleFactor * htmlScaleFactor);

            if(totalPdfHeight < htmlPageHeight){
                pdf.addPage();
            }
            safetyNet++;
        }
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution? If so kindly do post the same.

Comment: @RoyMJ Using image to pdf will give low quality PDF instead you could use autoTable for jsPdf and export the content with header and footer.

Check here https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#header-footer

It will also generate high quality PDF output.

Comment: @Purushoth: Thanks for the above link, but its not a table that im looking to import, but a lengthy html and the plugins out there seems to have a problem when it comes to lengthy contents

Comment: May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570767/pdf-images-not-displaying-in-firefox :
"This is the problem with the Firefox built in viewer. You will need to go to Options->Applications and change the PDF File or Portable Document Format settings to Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [canvas-to-blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

and modify this line:

```
pdf.save('test.pdf');
```

to this:

```
var data = pdf.output();
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}

var blob = new Blob(
    [array],
    {type: 'application/pdf', encoding: 'raw'}
);
saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
```

You can check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1I2CLhwKSnEoEggoZDe?p=preview).

It worked for me on Mac, Firefox.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330820/generating-pdfs-with-jspdf-compatibility-issues-in-firefox).

Comment: Also, any idea how to set all four side margins?